# Temporal density plot in R

Tags: r, plot, time-series, kernel-density

I have irregularly measured observations of a phenomenon with a timestamp each:

```
2013-01-03 00:04:23
2013-01-03 00:02:04
2013-01-02 23:45:16
2013-01-02 23:35:16
2013-01-02 23:31:56
2013-01-02 23:31:30
2013-01-02 23:29:18
2013-01-02 23:28:43
...
```

Now I would like to plot these points on the x axis and apply a kernel density function to them, so I can visually explore temporal density using various bandwidths. Something like this should turn out, although the example below does not use x axis labeling; I would like to have labels with, for example, particular days (January 1st, January 5th, etc.):

[image: kernel density plot]

It is important, however, that the measurement points themselves are visible in the plot, like above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#dput
df <- structure(list(V1 = structure(c(2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 5L, 4L), .Label = c("2013-01-02", "2013-01-03", "2013-01-04", "2013-01-05", "2013-01-11"), class = "factor"), V2 = structure(c(1L, 3L, 8L,  4L, 7L, 6L, 5L, 2L), .Label = c(" 04:04:23", " 06:28:43", " 10:02:04", " 11:35:16", " 14:29:18", " 17:31:30", " 23:31:56", " 23:45:16"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("V1", "V2"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -8L))
```

Using `ggplot` since it gives fine-grained control over your plot. Use different layers for the measurements and the density itself.

```
df$tcol<- as.POSIXct(paste(df$dte, df$timestmp), format= "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
library(ggplot2)
measurements <- geom_point(aes(x=tcol, y=0), shape=15, color='blue', size=5)
kde <- geom_density(aes(x=tcol), bw="nrd0")
ggplot(df) + measurements +  kde
```

Leads to
[image]

Now, if you want to further adjust the x-axis labels (since you want each separate day marked, you can use the `scales` package.
We are going to use `scale_x_date` but that only takes in 'Date'

```
library(scales)
df$tcol <- as.Date(df$tcol, format= "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
xlabel <- scale_x_date(labels=date_format("%m-%d"), breaks="1 day")
ggplot(df) + xlabel + measurements +  kde
```

This gives:
[image]

Please note that the hours seem to have gotten rounded.

Hopefully this helps you move forward.

Comment: +1 for the ggplot2 example, altough I don't understand why you follow such a complicated approach in constructing the data.frame, and you have an error in there too, i.e. columns dte and timestmp do not exist.

Comment: I constructed the df by reading from a csv, and then I used dput so that it becomes a reproducible example. The output of `dput` is why it appears complicated.

Comment: Aha, ok! No worries, it is a good answer anyway, I made use of it. I have some problems specifying a kernel bandwidth in the ggplot though. Maybe you could look at my other question as well? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16769305/temporal-bandwidth-for-ggplot2-density-plot?noredirect=1#comment24181407_16769305

Answer (score 0):

Convert your values to POSIXct, convert that numeric (i.e., seconds in UNIX time) and then apply your kernel density function. If `z` is your vector of timestamps:

```
z2 <- as.POSIXct(z, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", tz="GMT")
plot(density(as.numeric(z2)))
```

It would then be relatively easy to add a labeled x-axis with `axis`.